# My iPhone doesn’t delete Instagram data

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, instagram

A few days ago, I logged out of my Instagram account
when I wanted to log in again. The error below appeared in three of my accounts, but I could log in to any other account.

[image: Sorry, there was a problem with your request]

“Error:  Sorry, there was a problem with your request”

I erased all data and documents from my iPhone 13 Pro Max, but the data did not erase.  The accounts show me again and the same error.

I deleted Instagram data from iCloud, but the accounts shown in the picture remain in the application.

I want to take this step because there is an error in the application; I can log in from my accounts on any other phone.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try deleting the local instagram data using the Files app?

Comment: There is no local data for Instagram in the Files app

Comment: I don’t use IG so I cannot test, but there *must* be some localized data otherwise reinstalling the app would be blank, not pre-populated with your account info.  You may want to contact their support people

Comment: Do you want Meta to respond to user problems? Ha ha.. In general, if she had responded, I would not have asked my question

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 03/01/2024:**

With the app installed, go to your phone's Home Screen -> Settings -> At the top, tap yourself -> iCloud -> under "Apps using iCloud", "Show All".  Find and disable Instagram.

Also double check that Instagram isn't here:
Settings -> Passwords -> Instagram

THEN delete the app via Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage -> Instagram -> Delete App

Why:

When you log into instagram for the first time, it prompts you to save the credentials in a place where data will persist even after deleting the app. You must have clicked "Save Password":

[image]

Comment: It did not work. I did this step dozens of times...but the data and calculations remain as in the second picture.
  When you open the application directly, you are logged in with one of the accounts in which an error does not appear.

Comment: There is no problem accessing the web page. The problem is within the application itself because I tried it on a different phone and there was no problem

Comment: @QutaybaKhalid Give this new suggestion a try -- I believe it should solve your issue.